# Birthday Paradox expected value, only Monday

Tags: probability, combinatorics, birthday

Using an indicator variable, how many people do you need in a room so that you expect that there is going to be a shared birthday on a Monday of the year (assume 52 Mondays in a year and 365 days in a year)?

How do you approach this question?

I am thinking trying to use an indicator variable and modifying the original birthday paradox. I got 73 as an answer but I am not sure if I'm correct.

Edit: I was doing $\binom{k}{2}\frac{1}{365}\frac{52}{365} = \frac{k(k-1)}{2*365}\frac{52}{365}$ or basically multiplying the original birthday paradox's probability by 52/365.

Comment: What were your steps to obtain the result ?

Comment: The question is not well defined. You can have 101,083 people born on Sunday in the same stadium to worship the Sun...
I mean a question like "how many people are necessary at least to have a probability >0.5 that two of them were born on Monday" or something like this

Comment: You would need less than 73 people to get a probability larger than 0.5 if that is what you are asking. Why don't you show us how you obtained the result, so that we can see where you went wrong.

Comment: I was doing $\binom{k}{2}\frac{1}{365}\frac{52}{365} = \frac{k(k-1)}{2*365}\frac{52}{365}$ and I was looking for k to make the numerator greater than the denominator

Answer (score 3):

In order to solve the problem, I assume the simplification that a year has $364=52*7$ days. If not, the result depends on the calendar year, because it affects the various probabilities and the possible leap year.

Suppose we have $N$ people. Given the question, we are only interested in the people that have their birthday on a Monday this year. Therefore we need the probability $P(N,k)$ that $k$ people of $N$ have their birthday on a Monday:
$$
P(N,k) = \binom{N}{k} \left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^k \left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^{N-k}
$$ 
The next thing we need is wether within these $k$ people there are two (or more) that have their birthday on the same day. It is however easier to compute the probability that this is not the case. This is given by:
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{52-i}{52} = \frac{52!}{52^k (52-k)!}
$$
because there are 52 possible days for the first person, 51 for the second and so on.

Combining this gives us the probability $P(N)$ of having two or more people, among a total of $N$, to have their birthday on the same Monday:
$$
P(N)= \sum_{k=0}^N P(N,k) \left[ 1 - \frac{52!}{52^k (52-k)!} \right]
$$
where we now have to sum over every possible value of $k$. Using that $\sum_k P(N,k)=1$ this gives as a final result:
$$
P(N) = 1 - \left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^N \sum_{k=0}^N \binom{N}{k} \frac{52!}{6^k 52^k (52-k)!}
$$
If we now compute this for some values we obtain:
$$
P(62) \approx 0.494809
$$
$$
P(63) \approx 0.505526
$$
So we would need 63 people to have a probability larger than 50%.

If we assume a particular with 52 Mondays out of 365 days, the only thing that changes is the probability to select $k$ people out of $N$. This would become
$$
P(N,k) = \binom{N}{k} \left(\frac{52}{365}\right)^k \left(\frac{313}{365}\right)^{N-k}
$$
and for $P(N)$ we would get
$$
P(N) = 1 - \sum_{k=0}^N \binom{N}{k} \frac{313^{N-k} 52!}{365^N (52-k)!}
$$
The corresponding probabilities would be
$$
P(62) \approx 0.492975
$$
$$
P(63) \approx 0.503675
$$
The criterion that is used to determine wether there are enough people is $P(N) \geq 50%$. It is than more likely that such a pair exist than for such a pair not to exist.

Using the same approach, we can also compute the expected number of pairs of people that share their birthday on Monday. We already have the probability that $k$ people out of $N$ have their birthday on a Monday, so we only need to find out how many pairs among those $k$ share it on the same day as well. So consider an arbitrary couple $(i,j)$ out of the $k$ members of this class. The first person has his birthday on the $b_i$th Monday of the year. The chance that the second person shares that day is than $\frac{1}{52}$. Since there are $\binom{k}{2}$ such pairs, one would expect that there are $\binom{k}{2} \frac{1}{52}$ pairs in total. This is not guaranteed, it could be more or less, but if you are to repeat the process over and over again for many uncorrelated groups, that is what one would get. For the expected number of pairs among $N$ persons you would therefore get:
$$
E(N) = \sum_{k=0}^N P(N,k) \binom{k}{2} \frac{1}{52} = \dots = \binom{N}{2} \frac{52}{365^2}
$$
You can obtain the results faster by realising that for each of the pairs $(i,j)$ in $N$ people, of which there are $\binom{N}{2}$ the first needs to have his birthday on a Monday, with probability $\frac{52}{365}$ and the second has a probability of $\frac{1}{365}$ to share the exact same day.

The criteria one would use here to determine wether there are enough people, would be $E(N) \geq 1$.

Apart from the fact that the formulas are rather different, a simpler example might be more helpful. Consider a fair coin and compare the probability that there are one or more pairs of head to the expected number of pairs of heads among $N$ coin flips and take $N=3$.

Of the 8 possible outcomes : HHH,HHT,HTH,THH,HTT,THT,TTH,TTT there are 4 that contain one or more pairs, and hence the probability of having at least one pair of heads is $\frac{4}{8}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Now for the expected number of pairs. The triplet $HHH$ contains three pairs, and the combinations  HHT,HTH,THH each contain a single pair, giving a total of 6 pairs. Each combination has a probability $\frac{1}{8}$ and hence the expected number of pairs would be $E(3)=\frac{6}{8}=\frac{3}{4} < 1$. Which clearly shows that these criteria are different.

Comment: We are assuming there are 365 days in a year, would that change the answer? And is there a way to use indicator variable to make this easier to solve?

Comment: I think I get your problem. The question asks for the expectation that two people have a shared birthday on a Monday. What you calculate, however, is the expected number of pairs of people with a shared birthday on Monday. Those are two slightly different questions, and you would need to reformulate the problem if this is what you want to know. In that case your answer is correct.

Comment: I am not sure how they are different. I thought the question was asking how many people do you need to guarantee two people have the same birthday on a Monday on average.

Comment: That is definitely not correct. It is always possible, albeit very unlikely  that none of the people in the room have their birthday on Monday.

Comment: I added some comments and a simpler example that hopefully helps you to understand the difference between the two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If there are $n$ people in the room, the expected number of pairs of people sharing a Monday birthday is $\lambda = \binom n 2 52/365^2$, and the number of such pairs is approximately Poisson distributed.  So I would (in a rule of thumb, back-of-the-envelope kind of of way) solve the equation $\binom n 2 = 365^2/52$ or the equation $1/2 = \exp(-\binom n 2 52/365^2).$

Comment: Is it possible to use an indicator variable to simplify the problem?

Comment: I kind of did use indicator functions to get my $\lambda$ formula: the number of matching pairs is $\sum_{i<j} I_{i,j}$ where $I_{i,j}$ is the indicator that students $i$ and $j$ share a Monday birthday.

Comment: Can you tell me where I went wrong? I was doing $\binom{k}{2}\frac{1}{365}\frac{52}{365} = \frac{k(k-1)}{2*365}\frac{52}{365}$ and I was looking for k to make the numerator greater than the denominator.

Comment: You and I tried to find the $k$ that made the expected number of matching Monday birthdays close to $1$.  I too get $k=73$.  But to have the expected value equal to $1$ is not the same thing as having an even chance that there are matching Monday birthdays.  It's harder to calculate but not impossible.  I get $k\approx 55$ as the value  where the exact probability is $1/2$, and $k\approx60$ using a Poisson approximation.  The other commenters are right, you did not specify a precisely posed problem.  But your answer is reasonably close anyway.

Comment: WHy is having the expected value equal to or greater than 1 not the same as having an even chance that there are matching Monday birthdays? I thought the expected value means that on average we will have 1 match. Am I calculating the expectation incorrectly using indicator variable?

Comment: Consider a gamble where you have 1 chance in a million of winning a million dollars, and nothing otherwise.  The expected payout to you is 1 dollar, but the chance that you get a non-zero payout is 1 in a million, not 1 in two.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62330/discussion-between-kimchi-lover-and-tango-mango).